# CPAL - How to compress the input stream?

Tags: rust, compression, audio-streaming

```
fn write_input_data<T, U>(input: &[T], writer: &mut WavWriter<BufWriter<File>>)
where
    T: Sample + hound::Sample + std::fmt::Display,
    U: Sample + hound::Sample + cpal::FromSample<T>,
{
    let input_vec: Vec<U> = input.iter().map(|sample| sample.to_sample()).collect();

    let mut encoder = ZlibEncoder::new(Vec::new(), flate2::Compression::default());
    encoder.write_all(input_vec.as_slice()).unwrap();
}
```

How to compress the audio stream before saving it to a file? I tried using flate2 with no luck, as the U is of f32 type and ZlibEncoder accepts [u8] slices. Is there a way to convert input_vec to a [u8] without loosing too much data?

The end goal is to compress the .WAV audio stream as much as possible since currently 10 seconds = 3.5 MB.

EDIT: I think I understood the problem.

```
    let contents = read_file_bytes("test.wav").unwrap();

    // compress contents with flate2

    let mut encoder = flate2::write::GzEncoder::new(Vec::new(), flate2::Compression::default());
    let c = encoder.write_all(&contents).unwrap();
    let compressed = encoder.finish().unwrap();
```

This code works successfully for compression, so I guess the question is could I write somehow to a Buffer without creating a new file?

Also, the compression only has a ratio of 2.33. As the end files will be at least 345 MB in size, which is too much, is there a way to record audio from the mic where 1 second != 344.35 kB or that cannot be avoided at all, since it's configuration dependant?

Comment: You don't want to use zlib for audio. To get the kind of compression you're looking for, you need a lossy audio compressor. Look for MP3 or AAC compression code that you can integrate.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I figured out that the best way of reducing the payload size would be as follows:

1. Create WAV
2. Turn wav bytes into mp3 
3. Do a lossless compression. 

That would reduce the size from 1 second = 344.5 kB to 10 kB. However I'm not sure how to work with streams, I don't want to create new files for this but instead do it in memory. Hope I'll figure it out

Comment: Note that applying a lossless compression on an MP3 will usually result in a _bigger_ file than the straight MP3 so you can skip step 3.

Comment: Lol. Did not see that one coming - thanks!

Comment: You can also reduce sample rate and reduce sample size (8 bit audio, anyone?). As with most data reduction, you can trade size for quality/accuracy.